# Eclipse Marketplace error - Unexpected exception: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/repository/RepositoryTransport

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

When I try to surf the Marketplace in Eclipse it gives me this :

```
Unexpected exception: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/repository/RepositoryTransport
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

what might be the problem?
any solutions?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse you're using? Could be you're running in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334686

Comment: thanx for the reply man but i fixed it. I use Eclipse Indigo and i had used the helios repository.

Comment: Reviewing the different answers, it looks like lots of different things can cause this same error. The one checking for and installing updates fixed it for me on Neon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I experienced this issue when the **SOCKS** proxy in eclipse was incorrectly configured. My machine which sits in a LAN connects to the internet using an HTTP proxy. In the **Network Connections** tab in eclipse, i had configured the HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS proxy. The SOCKS proxy was not required in this case, and on **clearing the SOCKS proxy**, the error disappeared and Eclipse Marketplace became accessible...woohoo !!

**Resolution Steps**

1. In Eclipse, click Windows -> Preferences
2. Search for 'Network Connections' in the 'filter' textbox
3. Set HTTP and HTTPS proxies correctly ( If you are connecting to the internet using a proxy)
   *Note : If you are connecting to the internet without proxy, use the 'Direct' profile setting in the 'ActionProvider' drop down. Else
   use the 'Manual' setting.*
4. Set SOCKS proxy ( If you have a SOCKS proxy server configured), otherwise clear this row.
5. Apply the changes and save it.

Now Marketplace should become accessible for you.

For details on **Network Connections configuration** in Eclipse, use the following link

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm&_sm_au_=iDMfvB6nQs52SSSM

Answer (score 22):

This problem raises because you could not access your Internet via eclipse. There could be a solution among answers listed above. I solve this problem with different approach. Linux has built-in SSH support to it is always important to check the local host address. And also no need to bypass traffic. So you can Go to

Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.

Now remove the proxy bypass and clear SOCKS IP.

NOTE:- This will work if your have proxy server.
Thank You

Answer (score 11):

I have installed version 3.7.2 of eclipse indigo and run into the exact same issue (after a clean eclipse/marketplace install). I resolved the problem by updating the marketplace plugin to a more recent version (in eclipse go to "Help -> Check for Updates" and the update should be listed there).

Comment: +1 - I needed this as the version of Indigo that I had was 3.7.0. I found the Marketplace update among a great many updates to bring me up past 3.7.0

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same problem with eclipse indigo. I figure out the eclipse doesn't find the appropriate network Proxy for my network, because by default it uses window's proxy. So i just set windows network Proxy using control Panel or you can set it through Internet explorer.This worked for me.

Comment: I had to disable my proxy settings in Explorer and the eclipse juno marketplace worked properly :) +1

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but using firefox.  Fixed it by changing

firefox>tools>options>advanced: network tab: settings:

and then selecting Auto-detect proxy settings for this network.

After I did this eclipse connected to the marketplace with no prob.

Comment: This will have been because Firefox was your default browser and was therefore a client for defining your system's proxy settings. Thus, for those reading this Q for help, for Firefox, read whatever is your default browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you are a constant proxy changer like me for various reasons (university, home, workplace and so on…) you are most likely to get this error due to improper configuration of connection  settings in the eclipse IDE. All you have to do it play around with the current settings and get it to working state. Here's how:

1. Go to Window-> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection.
2. Change the Settings: Active Provider-> Manual-> check---> HTTP, HTTPS and SOCS
3. That's all, restart Eclipse and you are good to go!

Comment: Thank you,it is working fine,what a great answers this is

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue after making the switch to JDK 7 in Eclipse.

I solved the problem by changing the selected Installed JRE back to JDK 6 (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs). After making this change I could access the Marketplace.

Once I'd finished with the installing what I needed from the marketplace I switched my installed JRE back to the JDK 7 one.

Answer (score 2):

I suffered a similar exception, tried out all the possible proxy settings and later found that the problem is with `jre7`.

This is what worked for me:

I replaced `jre7` with `jre6` and now it's working fine.

`jre7` has some security issues so that was creating a problem in accessing proxy. if `java1.7` is your project requirement u can install `jdk1.7` and set java home as `jdk1.7`, but uninstall `jre7` so the eclipse backend and other system components will use `jre6`, but the developed application will be `jdk1.7` compliant.

Comment: You can run Eclipse under Java 6 without uninstalling Java 7, by passing the -vm argument to eclipse.exe: "C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" This works nicely because Eclipse will still launch your app in Java 7 because it runs under a separate VM

Answer (score 1):

Simply check you browser settings in the `eclipse windows -> web browser`. Eclipse reads the settings of the browser selected in this menu.

Answer (score 1):

I did nothing. Just restarted eclipse and tried after sometime. It worked!! May be marketplace.eclipse.org was down for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by (1) changing windows->preferences->gerneral->network connection: Active provider to "Manual". (2) configure the "proxy entries" below. Since my proxy listens on 8087 on my localhost, here is my configuration:

```
http : 127.0.0.1:8087
https : 127.0.0.1:8087
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers were the solution for my problem (though I'm sure they'll help some people).  My issue was not a proxy setting, nor was it my JVM version.  I'm using Indigo (3.7.2) and my Marketplace plugin (MPC) was indeed out of date, but Help -> Check For Updates did not list it so it took a while for me to realize that this was actually the problem.

I was able to solve the problem by manually upgrading the Marketplace plugin, via `Help -> Install New Software`, selecting the Indigo repo, and then filtering for `Marketplace` and installing the plugin from the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind a proxy, there should be a configuration script in your IE Lan setting. You can find it either in IE or google setting. E.g in IE

1. go to "internet options->Connections->Lan settings" and ***make sure "Use automatic configuration script" is selected***
2. In eclipse, go to "Windows->preferences->General->Networc connection and make it "**Native**"
3. eclipse should already find and select it. 
   E.g.
   Schema: HTTP
   Host: Dynamic
   Port: Dynamic
   Provider: Native
   Auth: No
   Username:           //blank
   Passwrod:           //blank

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue for Jrebel.
I tried all above, was not working for me.

**Solution worked:**

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Go to - Preferences > General > Network Connections
3. Change to Direct (all will be empty)

Jrebel activated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Using MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench 10.6. I have the proxy properly set in IE/Explorer... and if I change I can't get out of the corporate network. I have internet just fine. Eclipse just doesn't seem to use what is set. I actually DON'T think eclipse recognizes the IR proxy... I don't think it recognizes any proxy at all. So if you're behind a corporate security solution like me, and require a proxy, you're out of luck.

**FIXED:** MyEclipse was picking up the proxy, however you then must TELL it use them. 
Under MyEclipse>Preferences>General>network Connections, change Active Provider from direct to native, and you should double check the native proxies ME has discovered are correct.

Answer (score 0):

goto preferences => network connection

set proxy connection = Direct

Answer (score 0):

If you have google chrome. Then go to chrome Settings --> Change proxy Settings --> LAN Settings, then check Automatically detect settings then OK. Then hopefully things will start working

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected with Wi-Fi or LAN then just go to Eclipse preference -> General -> Network Connection -> Active Provider : In the drop down select "Direct" and apply. This solves the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I resolved it by removing java7 and added java6 in java compiler compliance on all my integrated java projects.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by:
 * goto preferences => network connection
 * Select the **HTTP** entry and press **Clear**.
 * Enter the settings for the proxy again
 * Select the **HTTPS** entry and press **Clear**.
 * Enter the settings for the proxy again
 * Press Apply Button