# Cannot access Eclipse Market Place

Tags: eclipse, spring

I have Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite). I cannot access the marketplace , it produces an Exception :

```
Unexpected exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

What is the solution ?

Comment: Give a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562012/eclipse-marketplace-error

Comment: @StarsSky none of the comments there helping !. I will install the plugins manually !. Thanks